# WebAPI - How to invoke model validation outside of an action/request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Does anyone know how to simply run a model instance through the model state validation mechanism?

I just want to reuse the system for something different. I have some models that I read configuration files into and I'd like to decorate them with data annotation attributes and validate the configuration file is setup properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you want to run `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator`. I think this is what gets called under the hoods.

Say you have a class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

You can then validate this object by running the following code:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(customer, new ValidationContext(customer), results, true);

    valid.ShouldBe(false);
    results.Count.ShouldBe(1);
}
```

Comment: This answer suited my use-case, though for people interested in how ASP.NET does it, check out http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt6-model-validation.html